# Why must ContextSwitch be atomic and how to achieve this in practice?

Tags: operating-system, thread-safety, locking, context-switch

Why must ContextSwitch be atomic and how to achieve this in practice?

I think it must be atomic because if it doesn't save the state of previous processes completely, it can cause problems for future contextSwitches.Inaccuracy, and wrong data.

And to achieve this, can we can use locks?

Does this make sense or am I oversimplifying things.

Comment: Most CPUs provide a way to do this in a single instruction.  As the context is for a single CPU, you may lock interrupts on that CPU and perform in multiple instructions.  The *lock* mechanism depends on the CPU and OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably the same assignment as you.

As the save operation requires several steps to save the value of CPU registers, process state, memory-management information, etc.. It is in fact necessary to make the context-switch atomic to ensure consistency.

To do it, it is possible to make the save method and probably the load method "synchronized", in order to make their respective steps execute in one block.

Comment: Context switch is ambiguous.  Often the MMU switch is a separate phase from the CPU registers.  The *process state* is maintained by the kernel, so it is often the last state to update.  The switch would normally take place in an OS.  Often the MMU kernel mappings are the same, so its ordering doesn't matter as long as it is done before returning to user space.